# Give user permission to manage a specific channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I would like to give a SPECIFIC USER to manage a SPECIFIC CHANNEL. I just tried MANAGE_CHANNEL and MANAGE_CHANNELS permission code. If it's CHANNEL, then it isn't creating the channel (as if I didn't execute the command), and if it's CHANNELS, then it creates the channel, but I haven't permission to change the channel's name, permissions, integrations... WHat to do?

```
message.guild.channels.create(`${message.member.displayName}`, {
                    type: 'voice',
                    permissionOverwrites: [
                        {
                            id: message.guild.id,
                            deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                        },
                        {
                            id: message.author.id,
                            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'MANAGE_CHANNEL', 'CONNECT', 'SPEAK', 'MUTE_MEMBERS', 'DEAFEN_MEMBERS', 'MOVE_MEMBERS', 'USE_VAD'],
                        },
                    ],
                        }).then(chann => {
                        let category = message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.id == "764203829603991602" && c.type == "category");
                        message.member.voice.setChannel(chann.id);
                if (!category) throw new Error("Category channel does not exist");
                chann.setParent(category.id, { lockPermissions: false });});
                console.log(`${message.member.displayName} létrehozva!`)
                break;
```

Answer (score 0):

`MANAGE_CHANNEL` is not a valid permission (as said in the documentation for the [Permissions](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions) class), so you have to use `MANAGE_CHANNELS`. By granting this permission, the user should already be able to modify the channel name and topic. For changing integrations, you'll also need to assign the `MANAGE_WEBHOOKS` permission (do note that to add a bot, a user needs the "Manage Server" permission as well). As to why you're unable to edit the channel name despite having the `MANAGE_CHANNELS` permission, I'm unsure, since it works perfectly when I tested it myself. All I can say is that you have to make sure that your bot has the "Manage Channels" permission on the server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try what you said and I will check your answer as accepted. I'm waiting for my boss right now.